# Getting a digital signature from an eToken/smart card into LibreOffice

Tags: libreoffice, signature

I successfully managed to make use of digital signatures in LibreOffice Writer by following [flatmtn.com/creating-pkcs12-certificates](http://www.flatmtn.com/article/creating-pkcs12-certificates)

But now I want to use a digital certificate from an eToken/smart card and not from the Mozilla keystore directory.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You have to ask the smart card provider to provide you "PKCS11" lib in order to load this lib onto Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

The Mozilla keystore (aka NSS DB) does not have to contain only your local certificates and private keys, but you can simply load into the NSS DB external PKCS#11 module, that will take care of the signing of digital signatures inside of your eToken/smart card.

The question is where to get this PKCS#11 module. Most of the Smart Cards are supported by the OpenSC project. Otherwise, you should get the PKCS#11 module from the vendor you got the smart card from. PKCS#11 is standard for accessing smart cards.